# Change Wordpress Upload Folder using wp handle upload

Tags: php, uploads

Below code is for uploading file through a form ... I want to change the default upload path for the upload to a folder called abc in the root of my theme.

I hope somebody can help me with this Below is my code

```
<?php
function upload_user_file( $file = array() ) {

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );

      $file_return = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('test_form' => false ) );

      if( isset( $file_return['error'] ) || isset( $file_return['upload_error_handler'] ) ) {
          return false;
      } else {

          $filename = $file_return['file'];

          $attachment = array(
              'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
              'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
              'post_content' => '',
              'post_status' => 'inherit',
              'guid' => $file_return['url']
          );

          $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_return['url'] );

          require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
          $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
          wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );

          if( 0 < intval( $attachment_id ) ) {
            return $attachment_id;
          }
      }

      return false;
}
?>
```

Form

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['upload']))
    {
       if( ! empty( $_FILES ) ) 
       {
          $file=$_FILES['file'];
          $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $file );

       }
    }
    ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="upload">
</form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't store user uploads in your theme folder! I would suggest you store them in a sub-directory of the default uploads folder.

You can use the `upload_dir` filter to temporarily change the path:

```
function wpse_183245_upload_dir( $dirs ) {
    $dirs['subdir'] = '/abc';
    $dirs['path'] = $dirs['basedir'] . '/abc';
    $dirs['url'] = $dirs['baseurl'] . '/abc';

    return $dirs;
}
```

And then in use:

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_183245_upload_dir' );

// Your upload code

remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_183245_upload_dir' );
```

Comment: Is there a way I can pass location to callback function i.e. `add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_183245_upload_dir', 'directory1/directory2' );` and use it to change upload directory?

Comment: Sadly no - are you uploading to many different directories, or just a few?

Comment: I was managed to change upload dir using global variable.
What I do is upload user files and I want them to upload them in ```uploads/user_id``` folder. So if user is uploading his own files you can use ```wp_get_current_user()``` to get current user ID and modify function above like:

```function wpse_183245_upload_dir( $dirs ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    $dirs['subdir'] = '/' . $user->ID;
    $dirs['path'] = $dirs['basedir'] . '/' . $user->ID;
    $dirs['url'] = $dirs['baseurl'] . '/' . $user->ID;

    return $dirs;
}```